# Grouping my imports into one file for each page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I currently have a page called 'manage.js' in my NextJS app.  At the top I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import PaginatedItems   from '../components/PaginatedItems'
import TitleHeadline    from "../components/ui/TitleHeadline";
import WithdrawModal    from "../components/WithdrawModal";
import { FaTimes, FaUndo } from "react-icons/fa";
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
```

After reading this [blog post](https://blog.anurag.tech/how-i-structure-my-next-js-projects#heading-creating-custom-files-for-components) I thought it would be a good idea to start grouping my imports because they are piling up.  I wanted to try it with manage page first to see how it would go.  So I created the following in components/pages/manage.js:

```
export { PaginatedItems } from '../PaginatedItems'
export { TitleHeadline } from '../ui/TitleHeadline';
export { FaTimes, FaUndo } from "react-icons/fa";
export { WithdrawModal } from "../WithdrawModal";
```

With the aim then of doing this in manage.js:

```
import { PaginatedItems, TitleHeadline, WithdrawModal, FaTimes, FaUndo }  from '../components/pages/manage'
```

Except it throws all sorts of errors.  I dont understand why; the most common error I get is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

So I tried just importing 'PaginatedItems' from /components/pages/manage.js, but still failed.  I changed it to a named export as well:

```
export PaginatedItems from '../PaginatedItems'
```

Which PHPStorm seems to like but the page still throws errors.  Originally I did use the `export * from` but that didnt work.

Inside `PaginatedItems` I have the following:

`export default function PaginatedItems(props) {`

I feel like i've tried everything, and nothing is working. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are exported as defaults, you can't import them like this

```
 import { PaginatedItems } from '../PaginatedItems'
```

but like this

```
 import  PaginatedItems from '../PaginatedItems'
```

to export these you need to acknowledge you are actually importing the default, name it as something and then re-export. You can achieve that by

```
export {default as PaginatedItems} from '../PaginatedItems';
```